# When is the Minkowski functional a norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a real or complex topological vector space and let $A\subseteq X$ be absorbing, balanced, and convex. Then the [Minkowski functional](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Minkowski_functional) $\mu_A$ is a seminorm. Can we add some conditions that make $\mu_A$ a norm? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511378/showing-that-px-inf-left-a0-frac1ax-in-k-right-is-a-norm-under-ce) post gives such a condition, but it assumes $X$ is already a normed space. I wonder whether we can formulate more general conditions in which $X$ is only a TVS.

Comment: $\mu_A$ is a norm if and only if $A$ contains no vector subspace other than $\{0\}$. See https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Minkowski_functional

Comment: @geetha290krm If $X$ is a complex vector space and $A$ contains only a real nontrivial subspace, does the theorem apply?

Comment: Actually I just realized the statement on Wikipedia assumes $A$ is balanced. Thus, if $A$ contains a real subspace, it contains a complex one.